# Ideas for making a grid system in Angular that allow for components to cover more than one division

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I'm looking to develop a component in Angular which will serve as a template for future projects. The idea is that this component is composed of a N by M matrix of rows and columns (easily accomplishable with HTML) in which the spaces are for other components.

The problem is that I want some components to be able to use up more than one space in this N by M grid. A chart for example may be of 2 x 2 in the N by M grid while a card for a number may very well be 1 x 1.

The problem is that I don't want to rewrite the entire HTML every time I want to, for example, move the 2x2 component along the grid.

[image]

In this example, the black grid is populated with some components (in color) that may use more than one space in it

So far the solutions I've been studying are:

- Using the standard bootstrap grid system (I would have to rewrite the HTML for components that use more than one space)
- Using a canvas (Found no way to "draw" a component in a canvas)
- Describe the size of the grid and the distribution of components in code, generating the HTML and using [ngx-dynamic-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-dynamic-hooks) library to show it (Doesn't allow for ngIf and ngFor in the generated HTML)

Is there an easier way to do this? Am I missing something? I welcome all ideas :D

Comment: https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/overview Have you tried ? You wrap everything in `<mat-grid-list [cols]="nCols" >` or  `cols="4"` if you stick to 4 columns. Then every of your component must be wrapped in a `<mat-grid-title>` witht the correct parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use https://material.angular.io/components/grid-list/examples

I replaced the `.ts` variable of the example to the one that matches your expectations. I would add the "opacity" variable to [style.opacity] to insert an empty placeholder on the first row of your example.

```
 tiles: Tile[] = [

    {text: 'ZERO', cols: 2, rows: 2, color: "none",  opacity: 0},
    {text: 'One',  cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'green'            },
    {text: 'Two',  cols: 2, rows: 2, color: 'red'              },
    {text: 'Three',cols: 1, rows: 3, color: 'orange'           },
    {text: 'Four', cols: 3, rows: 3, color: 'red'              },

];
```